# Google analytics - metrics mismatch while exporting data via API with various set of dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, powerbi

I am working on GA reporting metrics in Power BI via reporting API.

While I create a query with some very basic attributes like sessions and users, I get same values as I can see directly in google analytics dashboard.
 but when I add more dimensions and attributes, say, user type, pageviews or gender etc, alingwith users and sessions, the value of users and sessions is inflated.

I have tried to go through various documentations, where I know there are some restrictions that not all dimensions and attributes can be put together, but in this case, GA has allowed me to add these basic attributes togehter but the results are not matching.
Is there any documentation to explain this behaviur, or has anyone experienced anything like this.
has this to do something to do with binning, though I would expect, even if the difference is due to different binnings on different counters, the difference should be a smaller value, not the ones I am getting, which is huge(multiple times of error ) not just few percent of error.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across with this problem and the reason is because of a limit on [Google Analytics Core Reporting API](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192).

> ### Sampling thresholds
>
> Default reports are not subject to sampling.
>
> Ad-hoc queries of your data are subject to the following general
>   thresholds for sampling:
>
> Analytics Standard: **500k sessions at the property level for the date
>   range you are using** 
>   Analytics 360: 100M sessions at the view level for
>   the date range you are using

i.e. Once the data you are requesting is returning more than 500k sessions / rows of data in a query, Google Analytics will return sampling data but not exact data.

---

The way I work around with this limit is to break down the query into separate queries (to make sure the returned data is fewer than 500k rows) with a date filter (per year, month or day, depends on data volume) apply to each of it. Then append all the queries back into one.

**Sample M code:**

```
(year as number, month as number) =>
let
    Source = GoogleAnalytics.Accounts(),
    ...,
    #"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(#"...", {{Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:pagePath", {"ga:pagePath"}, {"Page"}}, {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:pageDepth", {"ga:pageDepth"}, {"Page Depth"}}, {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:pageTitle", {"ga:pageTitle"}, {"Page Title"}}, {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:date", {"ga:date"}, {"Date"}}, {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Page Load Time (ms)", "ga:pageLoadTime"}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Items", each [Date] >= #date(year, month, 1) and [Date] <= Date.EndOfMonth(#date(year, month, 1)))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks @Foxan. Then how would you join these queries back , as there is no unique identifier.

Comment: @emudria Not joining them back, but appending them. You can try [UNION in DAX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn802530.aspx) or [appending queries](http://radacad.com/append-vs-merge-in-power-bi-and-power-query).

Comment: Hi @emudria Does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.

Comment: Thanks Foxan but the issue I was mentioning is not related to binning or query size. It was more of not having proper and comprehensive GA guide. The only solution to my query was a complete hit and trial method with lots of wastage of time.

Comment: @emudria But the discrepancy between Google Analytics and Power BI is due to the the sampling threshold of Core Reporting API mentioned above right? And the above solution/workaround should have solved the problem? Or the above solution doesn't work for you at all?

Comment: my query was little bit different from this. "While I create a query with some very basic attributes like sessions and users, I get same values as I can see directly in google analytics dashboard. but when I add more dimensions and attributes, say, user type, pageviews or gender etc, alingwith users and sessions, the value of users and sessions is inflated."

Comment: @emudria Yes and the reason is because the underlying data returned is being sampled, instead of returning exact values because the number of sessions in the query is more than 500k. And the above solution should solve the problem if you breaks the query into subqueries with filter (on fields like dates) so that you can get the exact data. Or is the data wrong even the sessions is fewer than 500k for your case?